# Get the value of a read-only field in Serializer validation

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

Error:

```
TypeError at /api/answer/
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

serializer.py

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         fields = ('exercise', 'answer_text', 'answer_file','datesend')
         read_only_fields = ('datesend',)
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
       date = attrs.get('datesend')
       ex = attrs['exercise']
       dateend = Exercise.objects.get(topic=ex.topic)
       if date > dateend.exp_answer_date:
          raise serializers.ValidationError('Response time is over')
       return attrs
```

Comment: The error tells that tour `date` variable is `None`. Could you check if you actually pass that field to your serializer? or you can check the whole `attrs` objects just to see what fields are there.

Comment: Yes, I tested, the date variable was not in attrs, I do not know where the problem comes from, can you help me, please

Comment: Please add your code where you actually use the serializer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
date = self.initial_data.get('datesend')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**